# Saving multiple different polynomial regression objects in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, polynomials

I am trying to generate polynomial regressions of different degrees and save the model objects.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error as MSE

df = pd.read_csv("kc_house_train_data(1).csv")

X = df['sqft_living'].values
Y = df['price'].values

lm = LinearRegression()

def Poly(X, degree):
    poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree = degree)
    poly_X = poly.fit_transform(X.reshape(-1,1))
    
    return poly_X

models = []

for i in range(15):
    poly_X = Poly(X, i+1)
    model = lm.fit(poly_X, Y)
    model.append(models)
```

Where `lm` is LinearRegression() from sklearn.

I end up getting a list of models, but all the models are the 15 degree polynomial. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

edit: output of `print(df[['sqft_living', 'price']].head(10).tostring())`:

```
       sqft_living      price
0             1180   221900.0
1             2570   538000.0
2              770   180000.0
3             1960   604000.0
4             1680   510000.0
5             5420  1225000.0
6             1715   257500.0
7             1060   291850.0
8             1780   229500.0
9             1890   323000.0
10            3560   662500.0
```

Comment: Sorry about that, edited!

Comment: Please update your post with the output of `print(df[['sqft_living', 'price']].tostring(index=False))`

Comment: You may want models.append(model) instead of model.append(models)

Comment: I mean `print(df[['sqft_living', 'price']].head(10).tostring(index=False))`

Comment: output added, thank you!

Comment: `model.append(models)` does not work, as `model` is the linear regression model, I get "'LinearRegression' object has no attribute 'append'"

Comment: `models.append(model)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to recreate your model at each iteration. Try:

```
models = []

for i in range(15):
    poly_X = Poly(X, i+1)
    lm = LinearRegression()
    model = lm.fit(poly_X, Y)
    models.append(model)
```

```
>>> models[0].n_features_in_
2

>>> models[1].n_features_in_
3

>>> models[2].n_features_in_
4
```